# Filter by date in lit (Django)

Tags: django, filter

Imagine i have a list and a form to filter this list by date.

[image]

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this filter on the form?

I got it here in the shell , but I can not implement in form , the template.

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from core.models import Job
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date=datetime.date(2015,8,1)
>>> end_date=datetime.date(2015,9,1)
>>> q=Job.objects.filter(data_job__range=(start_date,end_date))
>>> for i in q: i.nome_job, i.data_job
```

I try in `views.py`

```
p = Job.objects.all()
q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
# buscar por job
if q is not None:
    p = p.filter(nome_job__icontains=q)
# dmin = datetime.date(2015, 8, 1)
dmin = self.request.GET.get('min_date')
dmax = self.request.GET.get('max_date')
p = p.filter(data_job__lte=dmin,data_job__gte=dmax)
```

I need something.

Comment: Your question is not clear your code sample doesn't even have a form in it and you are filtering a django query set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert your date before:

```
from datetime import datetime

dmin = self.request.GET.get('min_date')
dmax = self.request.GET.get('max_date')
min_date = datetime.strptime(dmin, "%d/%m/%Y")
max_date = datetime.strptime(dmax, "%d/%m/%Y")

p = p.filter(data_job__gte=min_date,data_job__lte=max_date)
```